# A way to use .load with wildcards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm using jquery, jquery mobile, js, html and css inside Phonegap for my android/ios app.

My grasp of js & jquery is pretty limited.

My index.html uses .load to call other html files into their namesake divs.

Is there a way to replace the following code:

```
$('#page01001').load('cards/01001.html');
$('#page01002').load('cards/01002.html');
$('#page01003').load('cards/01003.html');
$('#page01004').load('cards/01004.html');
..
$('#page01900').load('cards/01900.html');
```

(which takes up nearly 2000 lines of my .js file), with a single rule that'll do something like:

```
$('#pageIDENTIFIER').load('cards/IDENTIFIER.html');
```

so that any div named "pageWHATEVER" will .load an html file of the same name (minus the word "page")?

I've read up on jquery wildcards, but can't find a way to then take that wildcarded input and replicate it in the second part of the command.

To complicate it slightly, there are usually several places in index.html that'll reference the same html file:

```
$('#page01001').load('cards/01001.html');    
$('#pageX01001').load('cards/01001.html');
$('#pageH01001').load('cards/01001.html');
```

so the divs "page01001", "pageX01001", & "pageH01001" need to all .load 01001.html

And, there are plenty of divs that are just divs and don't need to .load anything. I don't want to affect those. Only divs whos name starts with "page.." needs a .load.

Is there a way I can improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `.each()` loop, and a regular expression to extract the page number from the ID.

```
$("div[id^=page]").each(function() {
    var match = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $(this).load('cards/' + match + '.html');
});
```

Comment: Jepp. Thats pretty much exactly it.

Comment: Followup question!  There are a few sub-directories that the html files could be in. "cards", "menus" etc. I tried changing the div id's for each category so  that in the above code [id^=card] goes to .load('cards/'), which worked great, but then I added the same code substituting 'card' for 'menu', but it fails. Is there any reason this code can't be repeated a few times with different variables?

Comment: @user5513718 I can't think of any reason it wouldn't work. You should post a new question with the details of what you're doing.

Comment: Found the problem. User error as usual :)  Barmar's answer was spot on!